# Python - saving a list of dataframes with specific names

Tags: python

I have a list of excel files obtained with glob. I want to save a sheet from each one as a dataframe with a specified name.

I want to do something like below, which returns TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
data={}

for f in files:
    week = re.sub('\D', '',f[68:79])
    df_name = ['Week ' + week]
    data[df_name] = pd.read_excel(f,'Sheet1')
```

Comment: the keys of a dictionary need to be hashable  which lists are not.   Remove the brackets from the line declaring the `df_name` variable

Comment: @user15404111 was your question answered successfully?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because lists are mutable an hence are unhashable.

You can try changing below line -

```
df_name = 'Week ' + week
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `list` to a `tuple`.

```
data={}

for f in files:
    week = re.sub('\D', '',f[68:79])
    df_name = ('Week ' + week)   # tuple in place of list
    data[df_name] = pd.read_excel(f,'Sheet1')
```